# Flowing items horizontally w/ center alignment within a container

Tags: css, css-float, alignment

My dilemma is this (and should be simple, I suspect): I have a container and a set of items (both divs).  The following CSS applies:

```
.container {
    float:          left;
    width:          100%;
}


.item {
    margin:         32px;
    text-align:     center;
    position:       relative;
    float:          left;
}
```

The .item itself is a container that could have almost any set of arbitrary elements, but they need to be center aligned inside of it (in my case, it typically contains a thumbnail image and a small caption of text beneath it).  While the above CSS allows each .item to flow horizontally the way I like, I can't figure out how to make the whole set center aligned (as opposed to flowing from left to right like it does now).

Comment: why you are floating divs when you set width to 100% and display to block?

Comment: Block display actually is redundant since they're divs, I believe.  Not completely sure I understand why it still works the way it does, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**
Change `.item { display: block; }` to `.item { display: inline-block; }`, take away `.item { float:left; }` and add `text-align: center;` to  `.container`

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/RQrRb/

You could also put an `.inner` div with `width:75%; margin: 0 auto;` and then put your `.item`s in *that*, if you are looking to have some space on the sides.

Comment: inline-block?  I didn't even know that exists...  Stupid w3schools.

Comment: That's not going to work in all browsers. Specifically IE6 and IE7 has buggy support. See my answer below for a truly cross-browser implementation.

Comment: Also... regarding w3schools check out: https://github.com/paulirish/w3fools/blob/master/index.html Soon to be published at: [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) (I think)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at this tutorial from Mozilla. It can be center aligned by just setting the parent container to `text-align:center;`

[Cross Browser Inline Block](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Answer (score 0):

`.container {`
   `width:          100%;`
`}`

`.item {`
   `margin:         32px;`
    `text-align:     center;`
`}`

Comment: This makes all the `.item` divs stack on top of one another. Thats not what he's looking for.

Comment: In his code .container width is set to 100% and .item is block. I thought he wanted .item divs to be stacked up.